# Parallel/Concurrent/Multi-threaded transfers to and from git server?

Tags: git, concurrency, perforce, transfer

In perforce we can enable parallel syncs/commits which means that if there are 200 new files that need to be pulled from the server the p4v client will open 5-10 connections to the server and pull concurrent files in parallel to one another.  This makes a huge improvement to transfer speeds meaning the difference of 30Mbps on a single thread or 240Mbps on 8 concurrent threads, especially because our depots receive 10's of GB's worth of updates weekly.

I've been looking around to see if there is something similar that I can enable with our Gitlab server but I have not been able to find anything yet.  This is the only thing I've found on the topic and it's just a request for git-annex: https://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/Feature_request__58___Multiple_concurrent_transfers/

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so would you be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Comment: Unless your network is not doing sensible link aggregation, there's no reason *in principle* that multiple connections should be faster than a single connection.  Of course in practice all kinds of crazy things happen...

Answer (score 1):

Git currently transfers the content in a single connection. It is currently impossible to send chunked content over its network protocol. As [torek mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36802548/142020) git does some processing to reduce the size of the data that needs to be transferred. So git typically transfers over its single connection less content than is reconstructed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not transferring objects one at a time (i.e., not doing this [the dumb way](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#dumb-http-D0tAHVHZIZ)), the client's `fetch` process uses a streaming connection between the client and the server, with [the client sending with a series of "want/already-have"s as the server offers a series of "have"s](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols), in order to figure out what objects the client needs.  Then, once the objects are agreed-upon, the server aggregates those objects into a *thin pack*.  This thin pack is delta-compressed against the objects the client is known to have.

For a non-shallow repository, the server can trust that the client has not only the rejected objects but also all predecessor objects, and therefore produce tiny pack files even for fairly large object sets (depending, of course, on what predecessors actually exist, and on the ability of the server to compress quickly against those objects).  For instance, suppose that the 200 new or updated files are pretty similar to 200 previous versions.  The thin pack may essentially consist of 200 sets of instructions saying stuff like "copy the old `1234567...` and then add six bytes in the middle" instead of "here is 200 gigabytes of raw data".

This kind of thin pack takes quite a lot of CPU time to produce, but transfers across even the slowest link in just a few seconds.

Obviously if the 200 new objects have no resemblance to any previous object, nor to each other, delta compression will not help.  In this case the thin pack will benefit only from whatever the zlib deflate compression produces.

In any case, the fetching client then receives the (single) thin pack file, and fixes it to be a non-thin pack by adding back the missing bases from the objects the client already has.  Hence as [T0xicCode answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36801933/1256452), there is only one file transferred anyway.